# How to convert axis labels in ggplot2 or plot using a custom function

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In the beaver1 dataset (a standard built-in R dataset) time (a vector of integers) is formatted as follows: 0 = 00:00, 830 = 8:30, 1020 = 10:20, etc. I've got a function that performs this formatting. So, I'm looking for a way to make a plot with `ggplot` or `plot` (both would be perfect) based on raw time values while using formatted values for labels.

P.S.

This is the converter function I wrote. It's damn ugly, so you're welcome to suggest something better. I hate how strings are handled in R.

```
convert.format <- function(str)
{
    while (nchar(str) != 4){
        str = paste("0", str, sep = "")
    }
    sub("(..$)", ":\\1", str)
}
```

**Edit**. Adding a part of the dataset. The dataset comes with the standard R package and can be obtained by entering `data(beavers)`

```
    day time    temp    activ
    346 840 36.33   0
    346 850 36.34   0
    346 900 36.35   0
    346 910 36.42   0
    346 920 36.55   0
    346 930 36.69   0
    346 940 36.71   0
    346 950 36.75   0
    346 1000    36.81   0
```

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you provide a sample of your data.

Comment: @eipi10 It's a standard dataset that comes with R. You can get it with `data(beavers)`

Comment: Guess I need to read a little more carefully!

Comment: You should post your proposed plotting code.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
fix.x <- function(x) sub("(..$)", ":\\1", x)
```

Read that as:  for each item in x, replace the last two characters before the end of the string ("$") with a colon followed whatever they were originally. I don't think you can use the "raw time" values because there are gaps because no values for the last two positions between 60 and 99.

Comment: It doesn't work properly with inputs of 2 (or less) digits. For example, it converts 0 and 10 to "0" and ":10" respectively instead of "00:00" and "00:10".

Comment: I tested it with suggested data. The examples did not have such an instance.

Comment: Nevertheless, I used your code to make the function a little less ugly.